# How to programmatically clone a Logic App

Tags: powershell, azure-logic-apps

Ideally, using the "Get-AzWebApp" and "New-AzWebApp" would be perfectly ideal, but these commands only work for Web apps, not other types of apps - like Logic Apps.

Are there complimentary commands to these that can clone an existing Logic App?

I need to use Powershell and not use Azure RM.

For reference, I found these commands at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-app-cloning) link, noting that it uses the above Az commands which don't work for Logic Apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are Logic App-equivalent [Get-AzLogicApp](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/az.logicapp/get-azlogicapp?view=azps-2.8.0) and [New-AzLogicApp](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/az.logicapp/new-azlogicapp?view=azps-2.8.0).